# Ruby testing : uninitialized constant Test::Unit::UI::NORMAL

Tags: ruby, testunit

I am integrating my scripts with Ruby **2.4.1**. Earlier all were working fine with ruby **1.8.7**

I am getting the following errors when trying to run tests:

***uninitialized constant Test::Unit::UI::NORMAL***

Ruby version - 2.4.1

test-unit    - 3.2.3

If anyone can guide on this, it will be really helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Would need more information to give you a better answer, but it seems that it is not finding test-unit. Have you added it to your gemfile/required it appropriately?

Comment: Yes i have added it in the script, earlier it was not added [ruby-18.7]. 
Please find the attached screen shot.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
 
If you need any other info please let me know 
  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyIwe.png